# Select colours for geom_point and geom_segment (the latter with conditional colour)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've been trying to plot at the same time data from two different variables (as points) and a segment that adopts a different colour depending on a condition. My data looks like this:

```
    x = rep(rnorm(100),2)
    y = rnorm(200)
    z=rep(c("var1","var2"),each=100)
    dat = data.frame(x = x, y = y,z = z)
```

Now I plot the points:

```
    p1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = x,y=y,col=z)) +
          geom_point(stat="identity") 
    plot(p1)
```

And looks like this:
The plot without the segment:

[image]

Now I include the condition for the segment colour, and plot again:

```
    s="j"

    if(s=="a"){  
       color_line <- "red" 
    }else{ 
       color_line <- "blue"
    }

    p1 <- p1 + 
          geom_segment(show.legend = F,aes(x=1,xend=0,y=0,yend=0,col=color_line)) 

    plot(p1)
```

The plot with the segment:

[image]

As you see, even though the segment should be blue, it is red. And I don't want any reference to the line on the legend. So what I'd like ideally is:

1. That the segment is the colour I specify in the condition, and that the points are coloured neither blue nor red.
2. That the legend only shows the names of the variables in my data ("var1" & "var2").

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you want in the end, however to get a blue line without having "blue" in the legend, you could do `geom_segment(show.legend = F,aes(x=1,xend=0,y=0,yend=0), col=color_line)` (?).

Comment: Such a tiny error wasted hours of my life. Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

When setting the colour of the segment manually, don't put `col = color_line` inside `aes()`. Doing so, your code works as supposed.

That is:

```
p1 <- p1 + geom_segment(show.legend = F,aes(x=1,xend=0,y=0,yend=0),col=color_line)
```